# Autocomplete for a reference field with taxonomy term content

Tags: views, 8, paragraphs

I'm trying to create a [Paragraph](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) with a [Views Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewsreference) field. The View itself has a context filter, which filters the node entities I created by the tid of a taxonomy reference fields. This all works well.

How do I manage to have the context filter option field (the one marked yellow in the following screenshot) in the edit form of the views reference paragraph have an autocomplete functionality? I don't want editors to memorize the taxonomy term's IDs, but instead type in the title of the taxonomy term and get suggestions on which term ID the editor wants to choose.

[image]

Comment: Edit your Paragraph's Form display and change the mode to an Autocomplete field.

Comment: @Beau That will not help, as I've already set the autocomplete on the viewsreference field. But this does only provide the autocomplete for the _View_ field in the form, not the _Argument_ field